# Salesforce Apex: Accessing CSV data in developer console

Tags: csv, salesforce, apex

I'm trying to use CSV data in an apex class. There are many articles written about how to parse csv data in apex, but not many on the first part: accessing the csv data in apex. I've looked into import wizard (and data loader) but this csv data is not being uploaded into any sobjects. Rather, the csv data will be used for a SOQL query.

So my question is, how do I upload a CSV and access it in the SF developer console (which I can then parse and run the query).

Thank you so much!

Zac

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is a nice example that i have used to create a csv upload and parse function nicely with. https://github.com/salk31/RedGiving

Comment: Their classes that the upload and parsing of data. You would need to adapt the attachmentuploadcontroller to store the csv somewhere